# How SSIS MergeJoin works and what is its time and space complexity?

Tags: performance, ssis, query-optimization, big-o

In the case of Inner Join and given that both sources are sorted, I think SSIS MergeJoin will iterate over the shorter source n, and search through the longer source m, and the time complexity will be O(nlog(m)).

Space Complexity will be O(n).

I am in doubt because I wasn't able to find this written in SSIS documentation.

Comment: If the time complexity is something different, say O(n^2), how is that going to affect your design pattern? Ultimately, you need to smash two lists together to solve the business problem and the time it takes is the time it takes.

Comment: @billinkc, how is that NOT going to affect design decisions? Do you ignore performance when you think of alternatives?

Comment: I do not see that Microsoft publishes big O notation for any product. I am able to find many references to people who have done their own analysis on .net collections but nothing from MS. The point I was attempting to make with my comment was that while formal notation is great for analysis, as the requested documentation does not appear to exist, one would fall back to testing whether a workload performs in the expected time range. If performance of the OOB tooling is acceptable, I move on to the next business problem. Best of luck finding or writing up your analysis of their code.

Comment: @billinkc I understand your point. Thank you.